# How to tell if user changed file in django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django `ModelForm` with an image field. I want to resize the image when the user submits the form, but only if they uploaded a new image. My code looks like this:

```python
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['picture', '...']

    def clean_picture(self):
        picture = self.cleaned_data['picture']
        if picture.file: #This isn't right though
            #resize it
        return picture
```

However it seems like `picture.file` always exists if the model being edited contains a file. I know I can check `request.FILES` back in the view, but that's very inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: It may be easier to also just store a last upload time at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can do this with [`self.changed_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data), which returns a list of the names of the fields where the value changed. Whether there's anything special about a `FileField` that would interfere I don't know offhand.

Comment: That did it. I just had to change the `if` to `if picture and 'picture' in self.changed_data:` (since it might also be `False`).

Answer (score 0):

In js,

- In JS, set a global variable file_changed = 0.
- HTML input tag < input ng-model="avatar" type="file" onchange="ChangeFile()">
- Lets say ChangeFile() will provide a small preview of the file to be uploaded
- In function ChangeFile set file_changed=1 once the file is selected.